# if $id ist = $id / make css class dissapear

Tags: php, css

I have a Problem. I am not really familiar with PHP and i got this code block over here. I Think it will be easy if the clause but i cannot get it together. I need an if clause for the where i can compare the category id's and just make the job list hidden when the category id doesnot match.

The code is:

```html
<ul class="uk-grid uk-grid-width-1-1 ">
    <?php foreach (wpjb_get_categories() as $ja): ?>
        <li>
            <?php if (isset($param["category"]) && in_array($ja->id, (array) $param["category"])): ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="<?php esc_html_e($ja->id) ?>" "<?php esc_attr_e("wpjb-search- " . $ja->slug) ?>">
                <?php esc_html_e($ja->title) ?></div>
            <pre> <?php var_dump($ja->slug); ?> </pre>
            <pre> <?php var_dump($ja->id); ?> </pre>
            <pre> <?php var_dump($ja->title); ?> </pre>        
            <div class="wpjb-job-list wpjb-grid">
                <?php $result = pjb_find_jobs($param) ?>
                <?php if ($result->count) : foreach ($result->job as $job): ?>                        
                        <?php $this->job = $job; ?>
                        <?php $this->render("index-item.php") ?>
                    <?php endforeach;
                else :
                    ?>
                    <div class="wpjb-grid-row">
                    <?php _e("No job listings found.", "wpjobboard"); ?>
                    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$param["category"]`? Is it an array with ids as the value?

Comment: its is a param for a search.

Comment: i think it is made like. if $ja->id is the same as $ja-id in the list the show me the job / else dont show it

Comment: Is this the line that is the problem? `<?php if (isset($param["category"]) && in_array($ja->id, (array) $param["category"])): ?>` Because in_array expects `$param["cateogry"]` to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a boolean (true/false) variable based on whether or not to show the div in your php if statement, like so:

```
<?php if (isset($param["category"]) && in_array($ja->id, (array) $param["category"])) {
        $correctCategory = true;
} else {
        $correctCategory = false;
}; ?>
```

Then you can toggle the div visibility by replacing the div open tag with the following:

```
 <div class="wpjb-job-list wpjb-grid" style="<?php echo (!$correctCategory)? 'display: none' : ''; ?>">
```

Comment: The idea is you set the boolean `$correctCategory` in your main if statement block at the top of the page making it cleaner for when toggling the in-line css later on.

Comment: ok and then make the jobs like. if correct then show else not?